# Unable to install PDFLib on PHP and Apache2 on MacOS

Tags: php, apache2, pdflib

So, I hope you can help me.
I can't seem to get the PHP extension of PDFLib to work on my macOS System due to some security features of macOS:

if I restart the server it says this:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdflib.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/ext/php_pdflib.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/ext/php_pdflib.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:\n\t/usr/local/lib/php/ext/php_pdflib.so: code signature in (/usr/local/lib/php/ext/php_pdflib.so) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapping process is a platform binary, but mapped file is not\n\t/usr/local/lib/php/ext/php_pdflib.so: file system sandbox blocked stat()), /usr/local/lib/php/ext/php_pdflib.so.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/ext/php_pdflib.so.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
```

code signature not valid?
Is there a solution or workaround?
FYI: Updated PEAR, PECL, PHP is Version 7.4.23, macOS BigSur 11.2.3 (20D91) PHP installed via Homebrew

Answer (score 0):

> no suitable image found.

this is an indicator that your used Environment does not match the supported platform in the PDFlib DSO.

Is it possible that you are using PHP on a new **Apple M1** (ARM) processor? Currently PDFlib PHP for macOS is only available for Intel64.

```
(1)$ file php_pdflib.so
php_pdflib.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

Is this the case which might apply to you?

You could check this by using `file` on your PHP executable and php_pdflib.so to check which platform you are using.
Currently you can only use PDFlib in PHP via Rosetta2 (Intel hardware emulation).

Comment: No, it was an Intel Macbook Pro. It was the right version with PHP 7.4 NTF.


I figured out that it was some problem with the built-in apache. It wants the extension to be signed by same authority as the ones using it, I think.
It worked when disabling Libary Validation system-wide, but that could not be the solution.

So I deactivated the built-in apache and installed the one from homebrew who apparantly doesn't have this restriction

Comment: Using a different Apache is fine, but this is explained in **PDFlib in PHP HowTo** Chapter 6.3 _"When SIP is enabled the PHP binary which comes preinstalled with macOS 10.14 Mojave accepts only signed extensions and extensions must be loaded from one of the protected system directories for libraries. Other extension directories are not accepted. The PDFlib DSO is signed by PDFlib GmbH, but installation requires some extra steps on systems with active SIP. These steps are not required for other builds of the PHP binary, e.g. those from Homebrew."_ https://www.pdflib.com/documentation/howtos/